# Git push another commit while a commit is in review in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I am looking for a way to push another commit while the previous commit is still in review and not merged to the repo.

For example:

> git add .
>
> git commit -m "my first commit"
>
> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

This commit is still in review in Gerrit. Now I did another change locally.

> git commit -m "my second commit"
>
> git remote update
>
> git rebase
>
> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

This will push both the commits again to Gerrit. Is there a way to push just my second commit before the first commit is merged?

Comment: If there was nothing happening on the git repo remote update and rebase effectively should not do anything. The second commit would be submitted into review, doing nothing to the first review, I'd expect. What do you see? Why do you remote update + rebase?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your approach. You can work this way without problems. You only have to know that if you need to amend the first commit (due to some review issue) you'll have to rebase the second commit to be able to merge (submit) it (see this following).

You're working like this:

```
BASE --- A --- B
```

If you change commit A you'll have:

```
BASE --- A --- B
   |
   |--- A'
```

And after the rebase, you'll have:

```
BASE --- A --- B
   |
   |--- A' --- B'
```

When possible, always try to work your commits "in parallel" because this way you can change any commit you want without one affects the others. Like this:

```
git checkout -b change1 origin/master
< edit, add, commit >
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

git checkout -b change2 origin/master
< edit, add, commit >
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

You'll have this:

```
BASE --- A
   |
   |--- B
```

Now if you change A you don't need to rebase B:

```
BASE --- A
   |
   |--- A'
   |
   |--- B
```

Gerrit will merge (depending on the merge strategy configured) the two final commits after the review/submit process.

Comment: great answer, but it may be better to explicitly give an example of the rebase command, as in `git rebase ...`